# DHL configuration error

Tags: dhl

I am trying to configure the dhl module in magento (not depricated), but I have this error in the log file

```
2015-02-19T09:00:35+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [1000] => Error #1000 : The requested Global Product Code  and Local Product Code  is not available based on origin country US postal location and destination country US postal location for payment country US. Please make sure data entered is valid before proceeding or contact our customer service.
    [__pid] => 1672
)
```

My configurations for the shop are -
Country: United states | 
City: Madera | 
Zip: 93637

Any idea why I had this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you’re trying to rate a shipment with an Origin of US and Destination of US. DHL Express doesn’t support domestic shipping in US, CA, and several other countries.

Comment: I got it now. You were right. When I change it to other country, which is supported by DHL I get a result. Thank you for the answer